# Backpropagation shapes do not match

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, backpropagation

I have been trying to create a 3 layer (1 input - 2 hidden - 1 output) neural network from scratch using numpy. The output layer has only 1 neuron. I am trying to use stochastic gradient descent with mini batches. What I have done so far is as follows:

```
N1 = 50 # number of neurons in the first hidden layer
N2 = 20 # number of neurons in the second hidden layer
for n in range(10000):

    weight_increment2 = 0
    weight_increment1 = 0
    weight_increment0 = 0

    for j in range( batch_size):

        # choose a sample randomly from training set
        index = np.random.randint( trainims.shape[2] - 1)
        layer0 = trainims[:,:,index]

        # convert it to a column vector and add 1 for bias
        layer0 = layer0.flatten()
        layer0 = np.append( layer0, 1)
        layer0 = layer0.reshape((1025,1))

        # feed forward
        layer1 = np.tanh( np.dot( w0.T, layer0))
        layer1 = np.append( layer1, 1)
        layer1 = layer1.reshape((N1+1,1))
        layer2 = np.tanh( np.dot( w1.T, layer1))
        layer2 = np.append( layer2, 1)
        layer2 = layer2.reshape((N2+1,1))
        layer3 = math.tanh( np.dot( w2.T, layer2))

        # backpropagation
        layer3_error = trainlbls[0,index] - layer3
        layer3_gradient = 1 - layer3 * layer3
        layer3_delta = layer3_error * layer3_gradient

        layer2_error = layer3_delta * w2
        layer2_gradient = 1 - np.multiply(layer2, layer2)
        layer2_delta = np.multiply(layer2_error, layer2_gradient)
        strippedlayer2delta = layer2_delta[0:N2,:]

        layer1_error = strippedlayer2delta.T * w1
        layer1_gradient = 1 - np.multiply( layer1, layer1)
        layer1_delta = np.multiply( layer1_error, layer1_gradient)
        strippedlayer1delta = layer1_delta[0:N1,:]


        weight_increment2 = weight_increment2 + learning_rate * layer2 * layer3_delta
        weight_increment1 = weight_increment1 + learning_rate * np.dot( layer1, strippedlayer2delta.T)
        weight_increment0 = weight_increment0 + learning_rate * np.dot( layer0, strippedlayer1delta.T)

    # update the weights
    w2 = w2 + weight_increment2
    w1 = w1 + weight_increment1
    w0 = w0 + weight_increment0
```

- `w0` is the input weights: 1025x50 (1024=input, +1 is the bias term)
- `w1` is the first hidden layer weights: 51x20 (50=number of first hidden layer neurons, +1 is bias term)
- `w2` is the second hidden layer weights: 21x1 (20=number of second hidden lyaer neurons, +1 is bias term)
- `layer0` is the input layer vector: an input sample (1024x1) and `1` appended to the end, making `layer0` a 1025x1 vector.
- `layer1` is the first hidden layer vector: After calculating `tanh( np.dot( w0.T, layer0))`, I add `1` to the end, which results with a 51x1 vector
- `layer2` is the second hidden layer vector: After calculating `tanh( np.dot( w1.T, layer1))`, I add `1` to the end, which results with a 21x1 vector
- `layer3` is the output vector: `tanh( np.dot( w2.T, layer2))`, which is just a nunmber
- `trainims` is the training set with size 32x32x1900, meaning 1900 32x32 images

While doing backpropagation, I omit the last rows of `layer2_delta` and `layer1_delta`, but I do not exactly know why I do it. I suppose it is because of omitting the `1` terms I append to `layer1` and `layer2`.

When I try to run the code, it gives the following error:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-98c3beb3b346> in <module>()
     62         print( "weight_increment1:", weight_increment1.shape)
     63 
---> 64         weight_increment0 = weight_increment0 + learning_rate * np.dot( layer0, strippedlayer1delta.T)
     65         print( "weight_increment0:", weight_increment0.shape)
     66 

ValueError: shapes (1025,1) and (20,50) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 20 (dim 0)
```

I know that the dimensions should match to obtain a 1025x50 matrix and update `w0`, but I could not come up with a solution. Maybe I am doing backpropagation wrong, I do not know. Can anybody suggest a solution for this problem?

Edit:
OK I have noticed my mistake. Previously I was doing

```
layer1_error = strippedlayer2delta.T * w1
```

which was giving a matrix, but an error must be a vector for a layer, not a matrix. Changing this line to

```
layer1_error = np.dot( w1, strippedlayer2delta)
```

fixed the shape error.

But still, can anybody check whether my implementations of stochastic gradient descent with mini batches, and backpropagation is correct or not?